# How to know who disconnected the session through qwinsta?

Tags: terminal

How to know who disconnected the session through qwinsta.

I have done it on a server,and i disconnected my friends session.But, while I checked the Event log I could find only the disconnected user(whom i disconnected) and his client machine ip.